# Matrix Algebra simplification with Inverse Covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I just derived this expression:

$D = \frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_2)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_2) - \frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_1)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_1).$

I see that in some books, they end up having  $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ together. How can I re-write this? My linear algebra is really rusty at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this :

$$ \tfrac{1}{2}[(x-\mu_2)+(x-\mu_1)]^{T}\Sigma^{-1}[(x-\mu_2)+(x-\mu_1)] \color{red}{- \tfrac{1}{2}(x-\mu_1)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_2)- \tfrac{1}{2}(x-\mu_2)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_1)}$$

where the 2 red-colored terms "compensate" parasitical terms that appear in the expansion of the first "big" term.

But these 2 red-colored terms have the same value because one is transposed of the other (expressions $X^T\Sigma^{-1}X$ and $(X^T\Sigma^{-1}X)^T$ are equal because both of them are real numbers due to the fact that $\Sigma^{-1}$ is symmetrical).

Setting $\mu=\dfrac{\mu_1+\mu_2}{2}$, we end up with :

> $$ (x-\mu)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu) \color{red}{- (x-\mu_1)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_2)}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer! Maybe I should have explained more what I mean by  "having $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ together". The expression I am trying to reach from my original expression is this: 


$D = (\mu_1-\mu_2)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}x - \frac{1}{2}(\mu_1-\mu_2)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1+\mu_2).$

Do you think it's possible to arrive in such kind of expression given my original post?

Comment: No, it is impossible because the expression you just gave cannot generate quadratic ("2nd degree") terms $x^TAx$

Comment: Hmmm this is a mystery. Is possible that the question is wrong? Could you perhaps look into this note i wrote I am pretty sure that up to that point I have solved is correct. https://i.imgur.com/FpnG6is.jpg

Comment: I have had a look at your document, but sorry, you have to write it in a cleaner way : some of the letters used are so tiny and ill-formed that I am unable to understand it .

Comment: I think i solved it. I'll try to post my solution later with better letters

Comment: Looking forward to see it.